# SQL query retrieving data from date period of MySQL db table where one of two dates has fixed month

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am coding a program where I can track my finances. In one of the components(JLabel) I want to see money spent from fixed_day_of_the_month to this day. The logic would be:

```
fixed_day_of_the_month = 10;
get current date of the month;
if (currentdayOfTheMonth > fixed_day_of_the_month){
getDates BETWEEN CURDATE() AND fixed_day_of_the_month;
} else if (currentdayOfTheMonth <= fixed_day_of_the_month){
getDates BETWEEN CURDATE() AND fixed_day_of_the_month of LAST month;
}
```

Any ideas on sql statement that could do the job? I am struggling with the last bit where I have to get fixed_day_of_the_month of LAST month.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be something like this:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM myTable, (select @fixed_day_of_the_month := 30) as a
WHERE 
IF(day(now()) > @fixed_day_of_the_month, 
 getDates BETWEEN CURDATE() AND fixed_day_of_the_month, 
  IF(day(now()) <= @fixed_day_of_the_month, 
   getDates BETWEEN CURDATE() AND fixed_day_of_the_month of LAST month
 ,0)
)
```

The variable date could be solved by something like this:

```
select 
    concat(year(now()),"-",month(now()),"-",18),
    DATE_SUB(concat(year(now()),"-",month(now()),"-",18), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I could have gotten *something* like this myself. Your query is obviously not finished/ready to go. What about that last bit where you have to define the last month: getDates BETWEEN CURDATE() AND fixed_day_of_the_month of LAST month?

Comment: StackOverflow will give you some hints, it's not a solve-my-problem-machine. Work with the query above and have a look at the MySQL-Docs according to Date-functions.

Comment: I am fully aware that stackoverflow is not solve-my-problem-machine. I am here to learn something. I have no studies assignment or job project pending. You have added no value with your reply. The complex bit where I am struggling is: getDates BETWEEN CURDATE() AND fixed_day_of_the_month of LAST month. Any insight on the that? I thank you for your time if you are here really seeking to help others.

Comment: See the [MySQL docs on Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Please, don't try to be a next google. I've seen these. I couldn't figure it out. I admit that. Now I am asking for help.